# FFmpeg - ANR on large files when mixing video and audio

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

This command

ffmpeg -i video.webm -i audio.m4a -c copy output.mkv

will always produce an ANR error in android at the end of the conversion for any large files, say greater than 700mb.

The ANR error is produced only at the finishing end of the conversion process after the output has been successfully generated, not in the middle or at the beginning etc.

So I suspect it has got to do with some I/O stuff at the end.
Can someone please shed some light into this, and help eliminate this ANR problem?

Comment: The ANR is not part of ffmpeg process *(you use Runtime.exec(), don't you?)*. It happens when your app consumes the result (output.mkv) on the main thread.

Comment: What do you mean by "consume on the main thread"? The command execution are done in a seperate background thread.

Comment: ANR <s>only</s> [usually involves the UI thread](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/anr). If you have the stack trace or some logs for the ANR, we could try to understand what exactly triggered it.

Comment: It does not produce any stack trace. Just that at the end of the conversion process, it just freezes the whole ui. No log, no nothing. The freezing occur only just when the file has just finished the conversion. I don't know if it might be one of those file IO stuff at the end.

Comment: Please post how you launch the converter and what happens after the child process is finished.

Comment: The command is given in the question already and it is executed on a different thread. After the conversion is finished, I just notify the user that it is done.

Comment: How do you know that the conversion has just finished?

Comment: Through a callback. https://github.com/bravobit/FFmpeg-Android

Comment: I would rather open a *[new issue](https://github.com/bravobit/FFmpeg-Android/issues/new)* on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

By default, **ffmpeg** produces progress output ~every 500ms. The way [FFmpeg-Android](https://github.com/bravobit/FFmpeg-Android) treats this output, it returns the progress message to your `onProgress()` callback, and also appends all these (relatively short) messages to a String, which is returned in `onSuccess()`.

What happens is, for a large video file the memory may get exhausted, or at least the Garbage Collector will work pretty hard. These String manipulations happen on the Main thread, which can easily cause ANR.

As a quick workaround, you can pass `-nostats` to the **ffmpeg** command line:

```
ffmpeg -i video.webm -i audio.m4a -c copy output.mkv -nostats
```

To resolve the issue, look at https://github.com/bravobit/FFmpeg-Android/pull/128.

Comment: Sorry to tell you but the ANR still exists. I believe the problem stem out from the core FFMpeg library, and not with the callback and string concatenation.

Comment: You mean, `-nostats` does not resolve the issue? Have you tried my change at https://github.com/alexcohn/FFmpeg-Android ? You cannot use `implementation 'nl.bravobit:android-ffmpeg:1.1.7'` for that, download the source form GitHub and use `implementation project(':android-ffmpeg')`

Comment: Sadly, it did not help either :(

Comment: I am afraid it's very hard to debug such problem remotely. How long does such conversion take until ANR?

Comment: Any conversion above 45 seconds roughly, ANR is producible only at the end of the conversion when the conversion is completed. Maybe FfMpeg does some heavy IO stuff at the end, my wild guess.

Comment: This doesn't happen for me even on few minutes run.